# OutOfMemoryError sending PDF HTTP Post

Tags: android, http, post, base64, out-of-memory

We are programming an application for android and, when we are sending a PDF file (via HTTP POST) to server, the application crash and this exception is shown:

```
09-14 15:31:59.253: D/dalvikvm(22978): GC_EXPLICIT freed 437 objects / 1236120 bytes in 47ms
09-14 15:31:59.296: D/dalvikvm(22978): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 29 objects / 1648 bytes in 45ms
09-14 15:31:59.316: I/dalvikvm-heap(22978): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.987MB for 5171605-byte allocation
09-14 15:31:59.359: D/dalvikvm(22978): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 40ms
09-14 15:31:59.394: D/dalvikvm(22978): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2 objects / 48 bytes in 27ms
09-14 15:31:59.410: I/dalvikvm-heap(22978): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.563MB for 6895468-byte allocation
09-14 15:31:59.453: D/dalvikvm(22978): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 41ms
09-14 15:32:00.089: D/dalvikvm(22978): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5 objects / 120 bytes in 23ms
09-14 15:32:00.117: I/dalvikvm-heap(22978): Grow heap (frag case) to 33.715MB for 13790920-byte allocation
09-14 15:32:00.164: D/dalvikvm(22978): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 43ms
09-14 15:32:00.214: D/dalvikvm(22978): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 13 objects / 6895864 bytes in 26ms
09-14 15:32:00.214: I/dalvikvm-heap(22978): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 13790920-byte allocation
09-14 15:32:00.242: D/dalvikvm(22978): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 25ms
09-14 15:32:00.242: E/dalvikvm-heap(22978): Out of memory on a 13790920-byte allocation.
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE JIT
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001d8b0 self=0xcd28
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   | sysTid=22978 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345017808
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:~45)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at java.nio.ReadWriteHeapByteBuffer.<init>(ReadWriteHeapByteBuffer.java:47)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at java.nio.BufferFactory.newByteBuffer(BufferFactory.java:49)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:52)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:317)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at java.nio.charset.Charset.encode(Charset.java:692)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:903)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at vetic.iventory.cds.CustomEntity.getContentLength(CustomEntity.java:69)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent.process(RequestContent.java:79)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor.process(BasicHttpProcessor.java:290)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:160)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at vetic.iventory.cds.CustomHttpClient.executeHttpCustomPost(CustomHttpClient.java:111)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at sql.vetil.edel.EtatDesLieuxBDD.sendFile(EtatDesLieuxBDD.java:176)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at sql.vetil.edel.EtatDesLieuxBDD.getReturnServer(EtatDesLieuxBDD.java:212)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at vetic.iventory.cds.P8$3.onClick(P8.java:224)
09-14 15:32:00.242: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-14 15:32:00.246: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8818)
09-14 15:32:00.246: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-14 15:32:00.246: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-14 15:32:00.246: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-14 15:32:00.246: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-14 15:32:00.246: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 15:32:00.246: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-14 15:32:00.246: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-14 15:32:00.246: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-14 15:32:00.246: I/dalvikvm(22978):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-14 15:32:00.246: D/AndroidRuntime(22978): Shutting down VM
09-14 15:32:00.246: W/dalvikvm(22978): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:45)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at java.nio.ReadWriteHeapByteBuffer.<init>(ReadWriteHeapByteBuffer.java:47)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at java.nio.BufferFactory.newByteBuffer(BufferFactory.java:49)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:52)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:317)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at java.nio.charset.Charset.encode(Charset.java:692)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:903)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at vetic.iventory.cds.CustomEntity.getContentLength(CustomEntity.java:69)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent.process(RequestContent.java:79)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor.process(BasicHttpProcessor.java:290)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:160)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at vetic.iventory.cds.CustomHttpClient.executeHttpCustomPost(CustomHttpClient.java:111)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at sql.vetil.edel.EtatDesLieuxBDD.sendFile(EtatDesLieuxBDD.java:176)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at sql.vetil.edel.EtatDesLieuxBDD.getReturnServer(EtatDesLieuxBDD.java:212)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at vetic.iventory.cds.P8$3.onClick(P8.java:224)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8818)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-14 15:32:00.253: E/AndroidRuntime(22978):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-14 15:32:19.394: I/Process(22978): Sending signal. PID: 22978 SIG: 9
09-14 15:32:19.554: D/dalvikvm(23043): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 973 objects / 71752 bytes in 31ms
09-14 15:32:21.046: W/KeyCharacterMap(23043): No keyboard for id 0
09-14 15:32:21.046: W/KeyCharacterMap(23043): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

The Error is raised in this fragment, used to count the size of the data to send (that means the file is still not ready to send):

```
try {
    size++;
    File f = new File(complexParametres.get(key)); // File to send
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
    System.gc();
    byte b[] = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    is.read(b);
    size += Base64.encodeBytes(b).getBytes().length; // Parameter encoded in Base64
    is.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error is in this line:

```
size += Base64.encodeBytes(b).getBytes().length;
```

Do you know how to avoid this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Streams support reading / writing small chunks of data. You shouldn't read the whole thing to memory, encode and send it. Read a chunk, encode & send and repeat until done.

Comment: What @zapl said, check ``android.util.Base64OutputStream``.

Comment: Your error shows that you try to allocate 13790920 bytes ~ 13790 kb ~ 13 MB of heap on a device, where heap sizes usually are in the 16-40MB range. As others said, don't allocate that at once. Also consider (for sending) that a GPRS connection may only be 64kbit/s.

Answer (score 2):

> check android.util.Base64OutputStream. – harism

Below code uses that to send a file Base64 encoded over any `OutputStream`. Just call `sendBase64Encoded(yourFile, httpPostOutputstream)`.

The implementation uses 4kbyte to send any size of file.

```
/** generic InputStream to OutputStream copy */
public static void streamCopy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}

/** close stuff that can be null, exceptions ignored */
public static void close(Closeable c) {
    if (c != null)
        try {
            c.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
            // silence
        }
}

/** does NOT close out */
public static void sendBase64Encoded(String filename, OutputStream out) {
    File inputFile = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream source = null;
    Base64OutputStream target = null;
    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        target = new Base64OutputStream(out, Base64.NO_CLOSE);
        streamCopy(source, target);
        target.flush();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close(source);
        close(target);
    }
}
```